# Scrape Table Inside Comment With HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'd like to scrape a table within a comment using HTMLAgilityPack.  For example, on the page
http://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=f72457e4 
there is a table with `id="team_pitching"`.  I can get this comment as a block of text with:

```
var tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., 'team_pitching')]");
```

however my preference would be to select the rows from the table with something like:

```
var tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(., 'team_pitching')]//table//tbody//tr");
```

or

```
var tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()//table[@id = 'team_pitching']//tbody//tr");
```

but these both return null.  Is there a way to do this so I don't have to parse the text manually to get all of the table data?

Sample HTML - I'm looking to find nodes inside `<!-- ... -->`:

```
<p>not interesting HTML here</p>
<!-- <table id=team_pitching>
    <tbody><tr>...</tr>...</tbody>...</table> -->
```

Comment: Code, data and error messages must be directly available in the post. Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post to provide concise example of HTML that reflects parts of original document you are interested in and at the same time demonstrates problem you have.

Comment: <!-- <table id=team_pitching>...</table> -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of comment is not parsed as DOM nodes, so you can't search outside comment and inside comment with single XPath.

You can get `InnerHTML` of the comment node, trim comment tags, load it into the `HtmlDocument` and query on it. Something like this should work

```
var commentNode = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., 'team_pitching')]");
var commentHtml = commentNode.InnerHtml.TrimStart('<', '!', '-').TrimEnd('-', '>');
var commentDoc = new HtmlDocument();
commentDoc.LoadHtml(commentHtml);
var tags = commentDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tbody//tr");
```

Comment: This works, however it doesn't specifically answer the question.